# Where should parts of a custom AngularJS directive be kept?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kineticjs

I'm trying to create a custom Angular directive that uses KineticJS to draw on a canvas based off values in the scope. I intend to create a service that will then update the scope based off a $http call that receives a JSON response. At that point I'd like the directive to loop through the values in the scope and create a kinetic node for each value.

However, I'm not sure if I should be doing this inside the controller or within the link function of the directive. If I were to do the updating inside the linking function, would I scope.$watch or something else?

I've created the custom directive like this:

```
angular.module('history.directives', [])
    .directive('kinetic', function() {
        var kineticContainer = '<div id="container"></div>';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile:function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                tElement.html(kineticContainer);
            },
            controller: KineticCtrl
        };
});
```

The controller then looks like this:

```
function KineticCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight - $('.navbar').outerHeight()
    });

    $scope.drawNode = function(posx, posy) {
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var group = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: posx,
            y: posy
        });

        var line = new Kinetic.Line({
            points: [0, 25, 500, 25],
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4
        });

        var text = new Kinetic.Text({
            text: 'www.google.com',
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
            fill: '#555',
            width: 300
        });

        group.add(line);
        group.add(text);
        layer.add(group);
        $scope.stage.add(layer);
    };

    $scope.drawNode(200, 400);
    $scope.drawNode(800, 400);
    $scope.drawNode(400, 100);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Difference between the 'controller', 'link' and 'compile' functions when defining a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546945/difference-between-the-controller-and-link-functions-when-defining-an-angula)

In summary, there is little difference between a directive's controller and link functions.  The controller will run first, if that matters, but I don't think it does here – since you are retrieving data via $http you'll have to use $watch in the controller or link function in order to trigger your logic when the data becomes available.

Comment: Ok, when you say to use $watch in the controller or link function... is there any reason why I should do one over the other?

Comment: @sailboatlie, for the code you show, either should be fine.  (A controller would be needed, e.g., if you wanted to define some methods on it that other directives could call, but you don't have that requirement here.)