# Choosing a directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, angularjs-directive

The title may be a bit misleading, but i could not think of a better description.

I wrote a directive which includes a `ng-repeat`:

```
app.directive('appDirective',function($purr){
    var template = '' +
        '<div ng-repeat="elements in queue">' +            
        '</div>';

    return{
        template: template
    }
});
```

If i'm correct, i can choose between two ways of providing `queue` to my directive

**1: via linking function**

```
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        template: template,
        link: function(scope){
                scope.queue =[];
        }
    }
```

**2: via controller**

```
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        template: template,
        controller: directiveCtrl
    }

app.controller('directiveCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.queue = [];
});
```

Which way should i choose, and why?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter.  Note that the controller will run before the link function.

Comment: Thank you. Could this fact cause any side effects?

Comment: I doubt it.  I have seen a few examples where people have set a scope property in a link function, and tried to access it in a controller function (and wondered why it didn't exist yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little difference between a directive's link function and controller function.  In general, you can put methods, $watches, etc. into either. The controller will run first, which sometimes matters. You may want to put scope-manipulation functions inside the controller just for consistency with the rest of the framework.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/xfh3F/) logs when the controller and link functions run with two nested directives.

See also [Difference between the 'controller', 'link' and 'compile' functions when defining a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546945/difference-between-the-controller-and-link-functions-when-defining-an-angula)

```
.
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Personally, I'd say that it feels more correct to apply a controller. On the other hand, i would have thought that the second way, is the more efficent one.