# Render AngularJS directive within jqxGrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqxgrid, jqwidget

Using jqxGrid to make a table with data (obviously).

I've got my angular directive element loaded in the jqxGrid, data updates the grid fine, but it just stays there, unrendered and I can't figure out how to trigger the rendering.

Here are my jqx settings:

```
   AppvisAgentsCtrl.settings = {
        autowidth: true,
        ...
        columns: [

            { text: 'A', cellsrenderer: insertActionMenu, width: 50 },
           ...
        ]
    }
```

Where insertActionMenu is simply this right now:

```
function insertActionMenu(){

    var output = [
        '<actionmenu></actionmenu>'
        ].join('');

    return output;
}
```

My problem is that in the DOM inspector, I'll just see `<actionmenu></actionmenu>` sitting there on the page in every column and I want to tell it to render into the directive it's supposed to be.

Yes, the actionmenu directive works I use it several other times throughout the application.

**EDIT**

Everything is inside jqx-grid directive:

```
<jqx-grid 
    jqx-settings="appvisagents.settings" 
    jqx-source="appvisagents.testData.things">
</jqx-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is happening inside a directive, you'll need to compile `'<actionmenu></actionmenu>'` before adding it. see `$compile` service [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: You mean in the compile function of the directive or in insertActionMenu()?

Comment: the $compile service can only be used inside a directive, and you need to compile adding the actionMenu directive inside the function, so that angular knows it needs to replace that with the real directive dom. I realise that code is probably not in a jqxgrid directive in your case so I´m not sure if you can do it. Maybe trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370390/how-can-we-use-compile-outside-a-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the only way I found this to work is to use the 'rendered' event in settings and $compile my actionmenus one by one.

Unfortunately, I could not $compile it before injecting it as jqx-gid will only inject text and HTML and any attempt to append an object results in `[Object object]` being appended.

```
AppvisAgentsCtrl.settings = {
        autowidth: true,
        ...
        columns: [

            { text: 'A', cellsrenderer: insertActionMenu, width: 50 },
           ...
        ],
        rendered: function(){ 
            $element.find('actionmenu').each(function(i,e){
                $compile(e)($scope);
            });
        }
    }
```

For me this is **not** a good solution for the following reasons:

- Despite having the jqwidgets imposed for this task, I wanted to avoid
  using jQuery as much as possible
- I don't know how this will affect
  performance over thousands of rows
- I still need to tinker to bind this directive to the data model corresponding to the row

However I did get it to render.

Comment: Did you find a better solution yet?