# How we can use the angularjs scope variables in the html which we are appending into the html page via controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code

```
var input = '<div class="form-group">{{variable}}</div>'
```

I have the above code which is written inside the controller. I want to push this element into the view and i want this variable value to bind from the controller ,but it is simply printing the same as `{{variable}}`. Can anyone tell me how to do this??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can we use $compile outside a directive in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370390/how-can-we-use-compile-outside-a-directive-in-angularjs)

Comment: The above answer is using `$rootScope` but you can/should bind the scope of the controller

Comment: $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="form-group">'+$scope.variable+'</div>');
and in Html ng-bind-html="data"

Comment: I am voting to leave this question open as the suggested duplicate has solutions that don't apply, introduce security risks, memory leaks, and other problems. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25458175).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive will bind the html and scope variable will be assigned to controller itself

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.variable = 'test'
    $scope.firstName = $sce.trustAsHtml("<h1>"+$scope.variable+"</h1>");
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-bind-html="firstName"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: While your solution will work, it's not a recommended approach (IMO) - It will not work if you will bind a directive to `h1` elements for example (It's probably not the case in this question, but still...) the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service is the best way to go

Comment: What is point of binding the directive in controller then if that is the place where I am initializing the scope data..? Like ng-repeat can be simply achieved by applying for loop in controller. Although I checked this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370390/how-can-we-use-compile-outside-a-directive-in-angularjs] and found it useful.

Comment: I don't have a solid example and I agree with your point. It's just that angularjs has a service specifically intended for this, that's why I commented. There's nothing wrong with your answer :)

Comment: I agree with [@sourav-satyam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11834630/sourav-satyam) that if the only thing the code is adding to the HTML is scope variables, it is best done with the [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive. The AngularJS team made a deliberate decision to **not compile** AngularJS directives in the controller and likewise with HTML from the `ng-bind-html` directive. It introduces security risks that are best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@sourav-satyam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11834630/sourav-satyam) that if the only thing the controller is adding to the HTML is scope variables, it is best done with the [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive. The AngularJS team made a deliberate decision to **not compile** AngularJS directives in the controller and likewise with HTML from the `ng-bind-html` directive. It introduces security risks that are best avoided.

The only thing I would do differently is use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$scope.firstName = $sce.trustAsHtml(`<h1>${$scope.variable}</h1>`);
```

### The DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.variable = 'test'
    $scope.firstName = $sce.trustAsHtml(`<h1>${$scope.variable}</h1>`);        
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-bind-html="firstName"></div>

</body>
```