# AngularJS directive loading before data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I'm loading a variable into $scope with $http:

```
$http.get('/teachers/4').success(function(data){
  $scope.teacher = data;
});
```

My template uses this data:

```
Teacher: {{teacher.name}}
<students-view students="teacher.students"></students-view>
```

This directive can load BEFORE teacher finishes loading, but my directive has code that depends on the teacher.students array being loaded:

```
app.directive('studentsView', function(){
  return {
    scope: { students: '=' },
    controller: function($scope){
      _.each($scope.students, function(s){
        // this is not called if teacher loads after this directive
      });
    }
  };
});
```

How do I get the behavior that I want here?  I don't want to stop using $http, and I would like to not have to assign a promise to the scope if possible.

Comment: what is happening in the loop? Can put that loop inside the success callback in controller if that helps or move the whole request to a service

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a watch to wait for `students` to be available. Once it's available you call the code that depends on it, then remove the watch. You can skip removing the watch if you want the code to execute every time `students` changes.

```
app.directive('studentsView', function(){
  return {
    scope: { students: '=' },
    link: function($scope){
      var unwatch = $scope.$watch('students', function(newVal, oldVal){
        // or $watchCollection if students is an array
        if (newVal) {
          init();
          // remove the watcher
          unwatch();
        }
      });

      function init(){
        _.each($scope.students, function(s){
          // do stuff
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between putting this code in the controller function, and putting it into the link function?

Comment: @Dave In the DOM compilation process, directive controllers get instantiated before link functions, so the link functions can essentially be seen acting on the end/stable state. The Angular docs recommend using [_controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#summary)_. Some argue otherwise: [Difference between the 'controller', 'link' and 'compile' functions when defining a directive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570008/2943490). It just depends on whether the aforementioned ordering matters to your use case.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to do some kind of watch on `students` to know when it is updated, then run your `_.each` when the watch is triggered:

```
app.directive('studentsView', function(){
  return {
    scope: { students: '=' },
    controller: function($scope){
      scope.$watch('students', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        _.each($scope.students, function(s){
          // this is not called if teacher loads after this directive
        });     
      };
    }
  };
});
```

More on `$watch`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope