# Showing Ionic popup to user, where to trigger? inside controller or directives link function?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My question is mostly conceptual. I want to show an Ionic popup to user once user taps a button.

scenario:

- inside a template, ng-click triggers the function to show the popup
- where is the correct place to write the function that shows the popup. Inside the directives link function or controller?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions already answered here in StackOverflow that could help you.

[Difference between the 'controller', 'link' and 'compile' functions when defining a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546945/difference-between-the-controller-link-and-compile-functions-when-definin)

[Angular directives - when and how to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post)

[AngularJS : link vs compile vs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller)

Basically you could define it in any of them, but take a look at the posts to learn a little bit more.