# Understanding step wise manual bootstrapping of angularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapping

I was going through the basics of angularJS about how it is manually bootstrapped. I came across different approach and found [this approach](http://plnkr.co/edit/FxANHN3jCly1O2gttibd?p=preview) to be best fitted.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
   angular.bootstrap(document,['myapp'])
})
```

Moving further, I came across [this another way which breaks it to basics](http://plnkr.co/edit/NGRGRaxh7rFC9OSjpUOr). I have commented the code as per my understanding but can someone please explain to me in more details about how things are working under the hood.

```
window.onload = function (){

  var $rootElement = angular.element(window.document);
  var modules = [
    'ng',       // angular module
    'myApp',    // custom module
    // what are we trying to achieve here?
    function($provide){ 
        $provide.value('$rootElement',$rootElement)
    }
  ];

  var $injector = angular.injector(modules);      // one injector per application
  var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');       // Compile Service: it traverses the DOM and look for directives and  compile and return linking function. No accecess to scope
  var compositeLinkFn = $compile($rootElement);   // collection of all linking function. Here scope is getting accessed

  var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');   // Hold of the rootscope
  compositeLinkFn($rootScope);

  $rootScope.$apply();
}
```

Also, please feel free to enlighten me more on this topic by suggesting more ways and improvements.

Comment: I think perhaps your question is too broad. Any chance you can narrow it down?

Comment: @hkBst: Not sure how to do in this ques. I want to understand what happens under the hood and I've provided all the steps. That's y i've kept bounty on this :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what are we trying to achieve here?
>
> ```
> var modules = [
>     'ng',       // angular module
>     'myApp',    // custom module
>     function($provide){ 
>         $provide.value('$rootElement',$rootElement)
>     }
>   ];
> ```

That is same old **dependency injection** we use everywhere in angularjs.
Here we are injecting the module `ng` and registering a [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value) into it.

And finally we are passing it in *angular.injector()*

```
  var $injector = angular.injector(modules)
```

Still not convinced? Here's the simpler version(the way we use DI in controllers)

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng','myApp',function($provide){
    $provide.value('$rootElement',$rootElement)
}])
```

Now two questions,

1. **why are we using angular.injector ?**

   Because, [angular.injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) creates an injector object that can be used for retrieving services as well as for dependency injection. We would need this to get *$compile* service and an *instance of scope* to bind that template with.
2. **why are we setting `$rootElement` ?**

   To let angular know the root element of application. Noticed the use of `document` in `angular.bootstrap(document,['myapp'])`? It is for the same reason.

   According to the [official documentation of $rootElement](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootElement),

   > **$rootElement** is either the element where ngApp was declared or the
   >   element passed into angular.bootstrap.

   Since we are neither using ng-app nor the standard angular.bootstrap method, we have to set this manually.

Next, we try to get `$compile` service from the instance of injector we just received from above step.

```
var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
```

The $compile service is the service to use for compilation. Invoking $compile against a *markup* will produce a function you can use to bind the markup against a particular *scope* (what Angular calls a linking function)

Again to get the scope, we use `$injector.get('$rootScope')` and pass it on to composite link function we got from $compile.

`angular.bootstrap(document,[myApp])` is just a syntactical sugar over above mentioned steps. It creates an injector instance, set relevant services with the help of it, creates application-wide scope and finally compiles the template.

This is evident from the [official documentation for angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap), which clearly mentions that it returns an injector instance.

> **auto.$injector** Returns the newly created injector for this app

Same story is indicated in the [official bootstrap guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

> Note that **we provided the name of our application module to be loaded
>   into the injector** *as the second parameter of the angular.bootstrap
>   function*. *Notice that angular.bootstrap will not create modules on the
>   fly. You must create any custom modules before you pass them as a
>   parameter.*

Finally, needless to say..all this has to be done *after* HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready.

**EDIT**

Here's a diagrammatic representation of this process.
[image: angular.bootstrap process]
<sub>(source: [dotnet-tricks.com](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Content/images/angularjs/bootstrap.png))</sub>

[Image Reference](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-angularjs-bootstrap-process)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It was of great help. Thanks :)