# What exactly do you do with the transclude function and the clone linking function?

Tags: angularjs

From the [directive Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), I see the compile function has 3 parameters, one of which is `transclude`. The only explanation the docs provide is:

> transclude - A transclude linking function: function(scope, cloneLinkingFn).

I'm trying to understand what exactly you would do in the clone linking function. I don't even know what parameters get passed into it. I found [one example](http://jsfiddle.net/vt8BF/2/) that has one parameter called `clone` that appears to be an HTML element. Are there other parameters available? Which HTML element is this exactly? I'm also looking at probably using `transclude: 'element'` in my directive. Do the answers to those questions change when using `'element'` instead of `true`?

I'm understanding transclusion with the simple examples, but I can't to seem to find more complex examples, especially with `transclude: 'element'`. I'm hoping someone can provide a more thorough explanation about all this. Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**EDIT: Completely and totally changing my answer and marking this as "Community Wiki" (meaning no points for me) as I was outright wrong when I answered this**

As @Jonah pointed out below, [here is a really good article on the compile option of directives and using the transclusion function](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/)

The basic idea is the compile function should return a linking function. You can use the transclusion function provided inside the linking function to take a clone of the transcluded DOM element, compile it, and insert it wherever it needs to be inserted.

[Here is a better example I've pulled out of my butt on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eydYuG5LGCQJBzsBJDJB?p=preview)

The idea of the compile function is it gives you a chance to programmatically alter the DOM elements based on attributes passed BEFORE the linking function is created and called.

```js
// a silly directive to repeat the items of a dictionary object.
app.directive('keyValueRepeat', function ($compile){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      showDebug: '@'
    },
    compile: function(elem, attrs, transclude) {

      if(attrs.showDebug) {                
        elem.append('<div class="debug">DEBUG ENABLED {{showDebug}}</div>');
      }

      return function(scope, lElem, lAttrs) {
        var items = [];
        console.log(lElem);
        scope.$watch('data', function(data) {

          // remove old values from the tracking array
          // (see below)
          for(var i = items.length; i-- > 0;) {
            items[i].element.remove();
            items[i].scope.$destroy();
            items.splice(i,1);
          }

          //add new ones
          for(var key in data) {

            var val = data[key],
                childScope = scope.$new(),
                childElement = angular.element('<div></div>');

            // for each item in our repeater, we're going to create it's
            // own scope and set the key and value properties on it.
            childScope.key = key;
            childScope.value = val;

            // do the transclusion.
            transclude(childScope, function(clone, innerScope) {
              //clone is a copy of the transcluded DOM element content.
              console.log(clone);

              // Because we're still inside the compile function of the directive,
              // we can alter the contents of each output item
              // based on an attribute passed.
              if(attrs.showDebug) {                
                clone.prepend('<span class="debug">{{key}}: {{value}}</span>');
              }

              //append the transcluded element.
              childElement.append($compile(clone)(innerScope));
            });

            // add the objects made to a tracking array.
            // so we can remove them later when we need to update.
            items.push({
              element: childElement,
              scope: childScope
            });

            lElem.append(childElement);
          }
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. First of all, isn't the first parameter into the transclude function the scope? I want to make sure I'm not missing something here. Secondly, When doing `transclude: 'element'`, what can you do with transclusion that you couldn't simply do in the compile function without any transclusion?

Comment: Actually, you can do this. http://plnkr.co/edit/naSbXc You can save some typing this way.

Comment: maxisam: I do realize you can do that, I was trying to think of an example, and this was the best I could think of. I guess I could have reversed the text or something instead.

Comment: Dnc253: the simple answer is that these two methods of transclusion are there to give you the ability to control everything about you transclusion via programmatic access to the process.

Comment: As for transclude taking scope as an argument, you're thinking of the injectable $transclude provider, which is slightly different from the one passed into the compile function.

Comment: I get crazy errors in my console on your plunk. Are you seeing those too?

Comment: I really don't think you should be passing the elem in as first parameter - it really does expect a scope.

Comment: what is 'clone' that is being passed as the argument?

Comment: clone is the cloned element from your directive's template. It's essentially the element that is going to be put where the directive is.

Comment: @blesh isn't `elem` that element? I mean `elem` is also put where the directive is, right?

Comment: Yes, and no... if you're replacing with your directive, that clone element becomes your element after transclusion. There's the elem: which is the element the directive *is* or *was applied to*, and then there is your template, which is cloned in inserted into your element, and if the directive does a replace, it actually replaces your element. I hope that makes sense. It is a bit weird, for sure.

Comment: In this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDKzfm?p=preview, `elem` refers to the actual directive but I logged `clone[0]` in console and it refers to a span which is appended to the template. Where did this new span come from? Shouldn't the `clone` be referring to the template elements?

Comment: Excuse, me, I'm confusing myself now... `clone` is a copy of the html content of your directive. `elem` is the directive's element. If you log the innerHTML of those elements, rather than the references, you'll get a snapshot of what they looked like when the code was executed, rather than an object reference which will only tell you what it's *currently* equal too in the developer tools.

Comment: The <span> is coming from the processing of {{name}}.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this accurately. Sorry about that.

Comment: @blesh, I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong.  If you open up the console and run your plnk you'll see this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`.  This is because you are passing an element into the first argument of the transcludeLinkingFn and it expects a scope.  It's spelled out clearly in the docs: `transclude - A transclude linking function: function(scope, cloneLinkingFn).`  Examples like this are not an intended use case.  [This article](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/) shows a better one.

Comment: @Jonah: You are 1000% correct. My answer was plain wrong. This was a while ago, and I've learned better. Regardless, I've completely changed the answer and set it to community wiki (no points awarded).

Comment: @blesh, I am very glad to see some members of SO care more about getting things right than ego.  Thanks for updating!

Comment: No sweat. I'm more mortified to think someone came across that and learned to do something the *wrong way*!

Comment: Just for others that come looking the [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) include some interesting new things.

`Note: The transclude function that is passed to the compile function is deperecated, as it e.g. does not know about the right outer scope. Please use the transclude function that is passed to the link function instead.`

This is due to it having it's scope pre-bound.

Comment: In your example I can see this line  childElement.append($compile(clone)(innerScope)); What confuses me is that it is called in the Link function; I thought the separation between compile and link function was due to performance reasons; and to avoid executing expensive tasks in the link function.

Comment: @ppoliani While it's true you don't want to do "expensive tasks" in your linking function, it's worth noting that your linking function shouldn't be fired very frequently. Generally it's only fired when a view is bound to a scope. $compile actually creates a function that will call the linking functions of directives it finds in the view. In this case, in order to wire up your newly cloned elements to the scope with the rest of the view, you need to $compile the partial view and call the returned function with the scope provided.

Comment: Transclusion in compile is now deprecated. It should happen in link.