# AngularJS - Local directive and parent scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting started with writing directives and I'm pretty sure I grasp the whole concept of defining an 'isolate' scope for a directive.

My directive `numberRoulette` is supposed to animate each digit (or a supplied number of digits through attribute `fields="some-number-here"`) in a supplied number with random numbers. Every elapsed second, one digit stops animating and is set to its intended number. It 's a bit like a slot machine..

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
    <span number-roulette fields="10" ng-model="number">
      {{number}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I make a two-way binding between the directive scope and a scope used by a controller `MasterCtrl`, my values stop displaying.

```
app.directive('numberRoulette', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {showNumber: '=ngModel'},
    ...
  };
});

function MasterCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.number = 1000;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nguyening/aX6Zm/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{{showNumber}}` or move `{{number}}` outside the span.

Inside the span, you have access to the directive scope properties only (e.g., `showNumber`), because an isolate scope was created for the directive.

Outside the span, you have access to the controller scope properties, e.g., `number`.

**Update:** ng-model isn't required here.  Any attribute will do, e.g.:

```
<span number-roulette fields="10" model="number">
```

Then in the directive:

```
scope: {showNumber: '=model'},
```

Comment: +1 as this is the right answer. But, for completeness, you could also use transclusion.

Comment: As per @Josh's suggestion, here is a jsfiddle that uses transclusion instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/aX6Zm/6/.  With this solution, we use `{{number}}` inside the span.

Comment: followup: say I remove the attribute `ngModel` from the span. If I'm `transclude`ing, how do I use the function passed into `compile` to access the sibling scope?

Comment: @actaeon, I'm not sure I follow you, but I think you're considering how to access the `number` property from the transcluded scope (since it prototypically inherits from the parent/controller scope).  I don't think this is how the transclude linking function is normally used.  From what little I've read about that function, it is normally only used to preprocess the content (i.e., "{{number}}") prior to being transcluded.  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183005/what-exactly-do-you-do-with-the-transclude-function-and-the-clone-linking-functi).

Comment: @MarkRajcok: how do I then go about modifying `{{number}}` within the `compile` function if I choose not to add it as an attribute of my directive, i.e. `scope: {localProp: '=attr'}`?

Comment: @actaeon, I would do this in the linking function (you don't need a compile function).  If you don't want an attribute, you can remove the `scope: ...` line from your directive and the directive will use the same scope as the parent.  Or you can use `scope: true` and the directive will get its own child scope that prototypically inherits.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/TwaDG/) of the former.  For more on directive scopes, see [this post/article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Comment: @MarkRajcok: Thanks for the help and resources! I guess I was stuck on the idea that I needed to use an isolate scope for my directive for it to be reusable in multiple instances, and I didn't want to pollute the parent scope with my functions and such. It makes more sense to inherit from the parent if I want to work with it this way.