# Add ng-click dynamically in directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that would allow an element to be defined as clickable or not, and would be defined like this:

```
<page is-clickable="true">
    transcluded elements...
</page>
```

I want the resulting HTML to be:

```
<page is-clickable="true" ng-click="onHandleClick()">
    transcluded elements...
</page>
```

My directive implementation looks like this:

```
app.directive('page', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var isClickable = angular.isDefined(attrs.isClickable) && scope.$eval(attrs.isClickable) === true ? true : false;

            if (isClickable) {
                attrs.$set('ngClick', 'onHandleClick()');
            }

            scope.onHandleClick = function() {
                console.log('onHandleClick');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I can see that after adding the new attribute, Angular does not know about the `ng-click`, so it is not firing. I tried adding a `$compile` after the attribute is set, but it causes an infinite link/compile loop.

I know I can just check inside the `onHandleClick()` function if the `isClickable` value is `true`, but I'm curious how one would go about doing this with dynamically adding an `ng-click` event because I may need to do with this with multiple other `ng-*` directives and I don't want to add unnecessary overhead. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn angular, and from what I've learned adding stuff dynamically is more of a jQuery thing. I think you should use an alternative approach with a static template. I encountered the same situation yesterday and I just do an if else in the click handler and add a conditional ng-class for styling if the button is not clickable. I agree with angular that having a static template is easy to read and predict functionality.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to just check inside the click handler for `isClickable` value for the time being... I just feel like there must be a way to add this during the directive compile phase! No matter what I try in the compile function, Angular doesn't hook up the binding to the function.

Comment: See my updated answer below for the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Better Solution (New):

After reading through the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) I came across this:

> You can specify template as a string representing the template or as a 
>       function which takes two arguments tElement and tAttrs (described in 
>       the compile function api below) and returns a string value representing 
>       the template.

So my new directive looks like this: (I believe this is the appropriate "Angular" way to go about this type of thing)

```
app.directive('page', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            var isClickable = angular.isDefined(tAttrs.isClickable) && eval(tAttrs.isClickable) === true ? true : false;

            var clickAttr = isClickable ? 'ng-click="onHandleClick()"' : '';

            return '<div ' + clickAttr + ' ng-transclude></div>';
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.onHandleClick = function() {
                console.log('onHandleClick');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Notice the new template function. Now I am manipulating the template inside that function before it is compiled.

### Alternative solution (Old):

Added `replace: true` to get rid of the infinite loop issue when recompiling the directive. And then in the link function I just recompile the element after adding the new attribute. One thing to note though, because I had an `ng-transclude` directive on my element, I needed to remove that so it doesn't try to transclude anything on the second compile, because there is nothing to transclude.

This is what my directive looks like now:

```
app.directive('page', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var isClickable = angular.isDefined(attrs.isClickable) && scope.$eval(attrs.isClickable) === true ? true : false;

            if (isClickable) {
                attrs.$set('ngClick', 'onHandleClick()');
                element.removeAttr('ng-transclude');
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }

            scope.onHandleClick = function() {
                console.log('onHandleClick');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I don't think that recompiling the template a second time is ideal though, so I feel that there is still a way to do this before the template is compiled the first time.

Comment: Good that you found a possibility, but i think that's quite messy. You should check out my updated answer.

Comment: I agree, and I'm not going to use this, but it does work at least. Still working on a better solution...

Comment: That's cool (your new solution). So now the template is generated dynamically. But I kind of dislike that using templateUrl is no longer an option, in case the markup is more complex.

Comment: Yeah, I think this solution only pertains to inline templates... You could probably use `$http` to go get the template during the `compile` phase, manipulate it, and then use my alternative solution during the linking phase and `$compile` it again. Sounds ugly to just get rid of binding though haha.

Comment: Your new approach is good. Although it has a little flaw (depending on your needs): It cannot change its clickable state dynamically. But if you don't need that feature, your solution is great!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but clickable state could be easily added and controlled with a scope variable (as other answers have noted). It's no different than hardcoding a template with or without the `ng-click`.

Comment: Another thing is that this will only work for an element but not attribute directive.

Answer (score 16):

You could always just modify your ng-click to look like this:

`ng-click="isClickable && someFunction()"`

No custom directive required :)

Here is a JSFiddle demoing it: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/5D4VR/

Comment: That's pretty neat! How would you assign the isClickable property to each button?

Comment: @Hans isClickable would be a variable on the scope and you could manually add it or any other variable to any ng-click in your html.

Comment: Although this works, it is not ideal because the `ng-click` directive is still being bound (and I'm trying to get rid of that, and declutter the bindings). See my updated answer for the correct way to solve my problem.

Comment: In your fiddle, buttonIsClickable is a variable on the scope of myCtrl. So wouldn't buttonIsClickable be exposed to everything on the scope of myCtrl? Say you make another button, then you'll have to define two buttonIsClickable-like variables on the scope?

Comment: @Hans yeah if you wanted to control two buttons seperately you would use two variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rob . Your solution is pretty simple and neat which suited my use case.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated answer

"The Angular Way" would be no manual DOM manipulation at all. So, we need to get rid off adding and removing attributes.

## [**`DEMO`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJl7yfcZPbVkGEECpls3?p=preview)

Change the template to:

```
template: '<div ng-click="onHandleClick()" ng-transclude></div>'
```

And in the directive check for the `isClickable` attribute to decide what to do when clicked:

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var isClickable = angular.isDefined(attrs.isClickable) && scope.$eval(attrs.isClickable) === true ? true : false;

        scope.onHandleClick = function() {
            if (!isClickable) return;
            console.log('onHandleClick');
        };
    }
```

You could also put the isClickable attribute in the directive scope so that it can dynamically change its behavior.

### Old answer (wrong)

`link` is run after the template is compiled. Use `controller` for alterations on the template before compiling:

```
app.directive('page', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        controller: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // your code
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, good idea though. I have tried this in the `compile` function as well without luck...

Comment: You are right. I created a new approach. Let me know how you like it.

Comment: Yeah that approach is my "fall back", and what I'm currently using as an alternative at the moment... I think there must be a way to manipulate the template in a directive before it is compiled the first time, don't you?

Comment: I think the "fallback" has a huge advantage: no DOM manipulation. Altering the template is not what Angular is meant to be. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: Don't get me wrong, in any normal situation I would (and should) use this approach. My question was about NOT using this though. I needed something slightly different to remove as many bindings as possible that weren't needed (I'm developing a complicated screen in a mobile app where performance was lacking). My example was very dumbed down.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div page is-clickable="true">hhhh</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('page', function($compile) {
                return {
                    priority:1001, // compiles first
                    terminal:true, // prevent lower priority directives to compile after it
                    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
                    transclude: true,
                    compile: function(el,attr,transclude) {
                        el.removeAttr('page'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop
                        var contents = el.contents().remove();
                        var compiledContents;
                        return function(scope){
                            var isClickable = angular.isDefined(attr.isClickable)?scope.$eval(attr.isClickable):false;
                            if(isClickable){
                                el.attr('ng-click','onHandleClick()');
                                var fn = $compile(el);
                                fn(scope);
                                scope.onHandleClick = function() {
                                    console.log('onHandleClick');
                                };
                            }
                            if(!compiledContents) {
                                compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
                            }
                            compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                                el.append(clone); 
                            });

                        };
                    },
                    link:function(scope){

                    }


                };
            });
```

credit to [Erstad.Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120386/angularjs-transclude-directive-template) and [Ilan Frumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687925/angular-directive-how-to-add-an-attribute-to-the-element)

BTW with  restrict: 'E' the browser crashed :(

Comment: Good thoughts, but this still has a `$compile` call (and it is kinda getting ugly haha) I've come up with a nice solution after reading through the angular docs. See my updated answer.

Comment: I agree it's very ugly :) but it's good to manage directive syntax :P and all in all I replied to the question ^^

Comment: and you've cheated :PP

Comment: Glad to know there is another alternative solution, I appreciate the answer for sure!.

Comment: Only with the appreciations my score does not increase ^^

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of the @DiscGolfer solution where I added support for attributes as well.

```
.directive("page", function() {

  return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: function(tElement, tAttr) {

      var isClickable = angular.isDefined(tAttrs.isClickable) && eval(tAttrs.isClickable) === true ? true : false;

      if (isClickable) {
        tElement.attr("ng-click", "onHandleClick()");
      }
      tElement.attr("ng-transclude", "");
      if (tAttr.$attr.page === undefined) {
        return "<" + tElement[0].outerHTML.replace(/(^<\w+|\w+>$)/g, 'div') + ">";
      } else {
        tElement.removeAttr(tAttr.$attr.page);
        return tElement[0].outerHTML;
      }
    }

  };
```

A more generic and full sample is provided  http://plnkr.co/edit/4PcMnpq59ebZr2VrOI07?p=preview

The only problem with this solution is that `replace` is deprecated in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be better like this:

```
app.directive('page', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var isClickable = angular.isDefined(attrs.isClickable) && scope.$eval(attrs.isClickable) === true ? true : false;

            if (isClickable) {
                angular.element(element).on('click', scope.onHandleClick);
            }

            scope.onHandleClick = function() {
                console.log('onHandleClick');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
module.factory("ibDirectiveHelpers", ["ngClickDirective", function (ngClick) {
        return {
            click: function (scope, element, fn) {
                var attr = {ngClick: fn};
                ngClick[0].compile(element, attr)(scope, element, attr);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

use:

```
module.controller("demoController",["$scope","$element","ibDirectiveHelpers",function($scope,$element,ibDirectiveHelpers){

$scope.demoMethod=function(){console.log("demoMethod");};
ibDirectiveHelpers.click($scope,$element,"demoMethod()");//uses html notation
 //or
ibDirectiveHelpers.click($scope,$element,function(){$scope.demoMethod();});//uses inline notation
}]
```

Comment: Add more info about how to use. At the moment this is useless.

Comment: ibDirectiveHelpers.click(scope,element,function(){//})