# Angular running ng-if with higher priority than ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a template with an `ng-if` that checks if something is an array and an inner ng-repeat that loops over it and re-applies the same template. Otherwise if its a string it just prints the value.

Unfortunately, it seems `ng-if` (600) has a lower priority than `ng-repeat` (1000), so even with strings, the ng-repeat just calls the template over and over again (I guess with each letter of the string) and hangs the browser.

Any ideas on how to make the `ng-if` run in higher priority? Or any other nice way to accomplish this?

**Directive**

```
app.directive('cell', function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            cellData: '=cellData'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.isString = function (str)
            {
                return angular.isString(str);
            };
            scope.isArr = function (arr)
            {
                return !angular.isString(arr) && angular.isArray(arr);
            };
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs)
        {
            return "/template/cellData";
        }
    }
```

**Template**

```
span(ng-if='isArr(cellData)')
    | [
    span(ng-repeat='inner in cellData')
        cell(cellData='inner')
        span(ng-if='!$last') ,&nbsp
    | ]
span(ng-if='!isArr(cellData)')
    span(ng-bind="isString(cellData) ? '\"'+cellData+'\"' : cellData")
```

**EDIT:** I solved the problem using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120386/angularjs-transclude-directive-template). I don't *really* get it, but I'm happy it works.

Comment: given that your ng-if & ng-repeat are on differnt elements/spans its not the priority which is the issue. issue is that ng-if is failing..

Comment: do console.log in your isArr function.. and check whats the input, its mostly arrayOfString, the issue would be with the JSON you are receiving, i guess...

Comment: what do you mean failing? I tried console.log in isArr and the browser hangs before anything is printed, that's why I assumed it's a priority issue

Comment: Oh yeah, so I removed the repeat and then did a console.log and it evaluates to false correctly, so why does the browser hang?

Comment: cant say why browser hangs :(, so you understood the real problem, right?

Comment: haha... I think the real problem is that the browser hangs :) I don't really understand what you meant by "ng-if is failing"

Comment: what is that you are getting as false... can you setup a plunkr

Comment: ok. so I did some tests and it's not the `ng-repeat` that's causing the browser to hang, it's the recursion of the template inside it. If I remove that there's no hang.