# AngularJS directive transclude part binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to use a directive, transclude content, and call directive's controller method within the transcluded part:

```
<mydirective>
  <div ng-click='foo()'>
    click me
  </div>
</mydirective>


app.directive "mydirective", ->

  return {
    restrict:  'EACM',
    transclude: true
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"
    scope: { } #required: I use two way binding on some variable, but it's not the question here

    controller: [ '$scope', ($scope)->
      $scope.foo = -> console.log('foo')
    ]
  }
```

[plunkr here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rj1Gd3YJZuAn5UGelYYw?p=preview)

How can I do that please?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same right now. have you tried using the transclude function directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a different answer, which is not a hack and I hope it will be accepted..

see [my plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCL3mhGC200N9KDBRbFY?p=preview) for a live demo

#### Here is my usage of the directive

```
<div custom-directive custom-name="{{name}}">      
  if transclude works fine you should see my name right here.. [{{customName}}]
</div>
```

Note I am using `customName` within the directive and I assign it a value as part of the directive's scope.

#### Here is my directive definition

```
angular.module('guy').directive('customDirective', function($compile, $timeout){
    return {
      template : '<div class="custom-template">This is custom template with [{{customName}}]. below should be appended content with binding to isolated scope using the transclude function.. wait 2 seconds to see that binding works</div>',
      restrict: 'AC',
      transclude: true, 
      scope : {
        customName : '@'
      }, 
      link : function postLink( scope, element, attrs, dummy, transcludeFn ){
          transcludeFn( scope, function(clone, innerScope ){
             var compiled = $compile(clone)(scope);
             element.append(compiled);
          });

         $timeout( function(){

            scope.customName = 'this stuff works!!!';

          }, 2000);
      }
    }
  });
```

Note that I am changing the value on the scope after 2 seconds so it shows the binding works.

After reading a lot online, I understood the following:

- the ng-transclude directive is the default implementation to transclusion which can be redefined per use-case by the user
- redefining a transclusion means angular will use your definition on each `$digest`
- by default - the transclusion creates a new scope which is not a child of the isolated scope, but rather a sibling (and so the hack works). If you redefine the transclusion process you can choose which scope is used while compiling the transcluded content.. -- even though a new scope is STILL created it seems
- There is not enough documentation to the transclude function. I didn't even find it in the documentation. I found it in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184889)

Comment: definitely the way to go. Thanks for the update, I forgot I asked that :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky. The transcluded scope is not the child of the directive scope, instead they are siblings. So in order to access `foo` from the `ng-click` of the transcluded element, you have to assign `foo` to the correct scope, i.e. the sibling of the directive scope. Be sure to access the transcluded scope from the `link` function because it hasn't been created in `controller` function.

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4j4X95hGo8SB2eCGCWrB?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'EACM',
    template: "<div> {{ name }} <br/><br/> <div ng-transclude> </div></div>",
    scope: { },
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.name = 'Should change if click below works';
      $scope.$$nextSibling.foo = function(){
        console.log('foo');
        $scope.name = 'it works!';
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Another way is assigning `foo` to the parent scope because both prototypally inherits from the parent scope, i.e.

```
$scope.$parent.foo = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if you remove `scope: { }`, then it should work since the directive will not create an isolated scope.  (Btw, you need to add `restrict: "E",` since you use the directive as element)

I think it makes more sense to call actions defined in parent scope from directive rather than call the actions in the directive from parent scope. `Directive` should be something **self-contained** and **reusable**. The actions in the directive should not be accessible from outside.

If you really want to do it, you can try to emit an event by calling `$scope.$broadcast()`, and add a listener in the directive. Hope it helps.

Comment: ok for restrict, just made a plunkr. I see your solution works but what if I want to keep the scope? I intend to use the directive several time in the same page + already use it to bind with other variables

Comment: is it possible to give the transcluded element the scope I desire or access the directive scope somehow?

Comment: @apneadiving I think it makes sense to call action defined in parent scope from directive rather than call the action in the directive from parent. Directive should be something self-contained and reusable. The actions should not be accessible from outside.