# Using linker function in a angularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been playing with angular directive recently and I have couple of question with regards to the link and compile functions.

I have the following two directives, which have the same funcitonality:

```
App.directive('repeatX', function(){
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    compile: function(element, attr, linker){  
      console.log('Compile repeatX');
      return function(scope, $element, attrs, ctrl){
        console.log('Link repeatX');
        var parent = $element.parent();

        for(var i = 0; i < Number(attrs.repeatX) - 1;i++){
          var childScope = scope.$new();
          linker(childScope, function(clone){
            $element.after(clone.attr('repeat-x', 0));
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

App.directive('repeatX2', function(){
  return {
    compile: function(element, attrs){
      console.log('Compile repeatX2');
      for(var i = 0; i < Number(attrs.repeatX2) - 1;i++){
        element.after(element.clone().attr('repeat-X2', 0));
      }

      return function(){
        console.log('Link repeatX2');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

It seems that the two directive are pretty much doing the same thing, but I quite don't understand why `Compile repeatX2` is displayed `n` times whereas the `Compile repeatX` only once.

The second question is, what is the exact job of the `linker` function?

I have a working example here: http://jsbin.com/rugohido/10/edit

Comment: what is your angular version?

Comment: That `linker` function you refer to is deprecated as of Angular 1.2. It is now made available in `link` instead, not `compile`. As for it's purpose, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183005/what-exactly-do-you-do-with-the-transclude-function-and-the-clone-linking-functi.