# Something like "with variable" in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Sample controller data:

```
$scope.items = [{ id: 1, name: 'First'}, { id: 2, name: 'Second'}];
```

Is there something in angular to make the following code work like "with variable"?

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="items">{{id}} {{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}} {{i.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Please feel free to make a more understandable title/question.

Comment: You can actually write a custom directive for that.

Comment: I would attempt a full answer if I were less tired but I think what you'd need to do is create a directive that uses `transclude: 'element'` and that calls `$scope.$watchCollection`. `ng-repeat` does these things.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Angular [ngRepeat document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), currently only followings expressions are supported.

1. variable in expression
2. (key, value) in expression
3. variable in expression track by tracking_expression
4. variable in expression as alias_expression

This means, you can't simply use `ng-repeat="items"` to iterate the collection.

BTW, `ng-repeat` will create a separate scope for each element and bind `variable` or `(key, value)` to the newly created scope. So "with variable" you refer to is not Angular built-in. You need to create a customized directive for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred answer would be "don't do this" but failing that, and because it's interesting, here's a proof of concept, assisted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183005/what-exactly-do-you-do-with-the-transclude-function-and-the-clone-linking-functi) and mostly adapted from [this blog post](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/):

```
app.directive('myRepeat', function(){
  return {
    transclude : 'element',
    compile : function(element, attrs, linker){
      return function($scope, $element, $attr){
        var collectionExpr = attrs.myRepeat;
        var parent = $element.parent();
        var elements = [];

        // $watchCollection is called everytime the collection is modified
        $scope.$watchCollection(collectionExpr, function(collection) {
          var i, block, childScope;

          // check if elements have already been rendered
          if(elements.length > 0){
            // if so remove them from DOM, and destroy their scope
            for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
              elements[i].el.remove();
              elements[i].scope.$destroy();
            };
            elements = [];
          }

          for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            // create a new scope for every element in the collection.
            childScope = $scope.$new();

            // ***
            // This is the bit that makes it behave like a `with` 
            // statement -- we assign the item's attributes to the
            // child scope one by one, rather than simply adding
            // the item itself.
            angular.forEach(collection[i], function(v, k) {
              childScope[k] = v;
            });
            // ***

            linker(childScope, function(clone){
              // clone the transcluded element, passing in the new scope.
              parent.append(clone); // add to DOM
              block = {};
              block.el = clone;
              block.scope = childScope;
              elements.push(block);
            });
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And then this will do what you want:

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = [
    {a: 123, b: 234},
    {a: 321, b: 432}
  ];
});
```

With the HTML structure you want:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <ul>
    <li my-repeat="items">
      {{ a }} {{ b }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Notice that given the attributes are copied into the child scopes, rather than referenced, if changes are made to the view, they won't affect the model (ie. the parent `items` list), severely limiting the usefulness of this directive. You could hack around this with an extra `scope.$watch` but it'd almost certainly be less fuss to use `ng-repeat` as it's normally used.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why other users are telling you that what you want has to be done via a new directive. This is a working snippet.

```js
angular.module("Snippet",[]).controller("List",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.items = [{ id: 1, name: 'First'}, { id: 2, name: 'Second'}];
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Snippet" ng-controller="List as list">

  <ul>
    <!-- Iterating the array -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <!-- Iterating each object of the array -->
      <span ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{value}} </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</body>
```

Simply, you need to iterate the elements of the array via `ng-repeat`, then you can do what you want with the object `item` retrieved. If you want to show its values, for example, as it seems for your question, then a new `ng-repeat` gets the job done.