# how to write a 'double' and a 'ntimes' directive for angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble understand the 'ngRepeat' directive so I wish to learn how angularjs works by writing a 'double' directive and then extending with an 'ntimes' directive:
so

### 'double'

```
<double>
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
</double>
```

would result in producing:

```
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
```

### 'ntimes'

```
<ntimes repeat=10>
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
</ntimes>
```

would result in producing:

```
 <h1>Hello World</h1> 
 .... 8 more times....
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<double>
 <h1>Hello World - 2</h1>
</double>

<ntimes repeat=10>
    <h1>Hello World - 10</h1>
    <h4>More text</h4>
</ntimes>
```

The directives below will remove the `<double>, </double>, <ntimes ...>` and `</ntimes>` tags:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('double', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
            var content = tElement.children();
            tElement.append(content.clone());
            tElement.replaceWith(tElement.children());
        }
    }
});
app.directive('ntimes', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
            var content = tElement.children();
            for (var i = 0; i < attrs.repeat - 1; i++) {
                tElement.append(content.clone());
            }
            tElement.replaceWith(tElement.children());
        }
    }
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/QkXcH/)

I used a compile function rather than a linking function because it seemed like only template DOM manipulation was required.

**Update:** I like this implementation of the ntimes compile function better:

```
compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
    var content = tElement.children();
    var repeatedContent = content.clone();
    for (var i = 2; i <= attrs.repeat; i++) {
        repeatedContent.append(content.clone());
    }
    tElement.replaceWith(repeatedContent);
}
```

Comment: In the original samples, why is there tElement.replaceWith in the end?  Isn't tElement already the same before replaceWith?

Comment: @mr_eko The `tElement.replaceWith` replaces the element with it's children. So `<double><h1>Hello World - 2</h1></double>` would become `<h1>Hello World - 2</h1><h1>Hello World - 2</h1>` (<double> is replaced).

Comment: very nice examples as usage of compile function

Comment: why don't the directives work without using clone? it seems when i log out content.clone and content they are the same thing

Comment: @Mark Rajcok 
I 've modified your sample a little bit, adding some attribute directive to content of `double` directive. Here is link http://jsfiddle.net/wjkv83ta/
And got strange behaviour: first element are not parsed correctly. You can see it, because anly second element bacome red.

Answer (score 6):

The `ng-repeat` directive is mainly used to iterate over items on lists/arrays/collections (i.e. `ng-repeat="item in list"`) and does much more than simply cloning elements. Please take a look at angularjs [ng-repeat directive documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat).

If you really just want to clone elements, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hp9d7/

Comment: Thanks! I just realised though that you used the link phase to add elements. Is it possible to do it with bindings as well?