# How to make AngularJS compile the code generated by directive?

Tags: angularjs

Please help me on, How can we make AngularJS compile the code generated by directive ?

You can even find the same code here, http://jsbin.com/obuqip/4/edit

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    {{names[0]}} {{names[1]}}
    <br/> <hello-world my-username="names[0]"></hello-world>
    <br/> <hello-world my-username="names[1]"></hello-world>
    <br/><button ng-click="clicked()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var components= angular.module('components', []);
components.controller("myController",
    function ($scope) {
        var counter = 1;
        $scope.names = ["Number0","lorem","Epsum"];
        $scope.clicked = function() {
            $scope.names[0] = "Number" + counter++;
        };
    }
);

// **Here is the directive code**
components.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    var directiveObj =  {
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var strTemplate, strUserT = attrs.myUsername || "";
            console.log(strUserT);
            if(strUserT) {
                strTemplate = "<DIV> Hello" + "{{" + strUserT +"}} </DIV>" ;
            } else {
                strTemplate = "<DIV>Sorry, No user to greet!</DIV>" ;
            }
            element.replaceWith(strTemplate);
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
    return directiveObj;
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a version that doesn't use a compile function nor a link function:

```
myApp.directive('helloWorld', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myUsername: '@'
    },
    template: '<span><div ng-show="myUsername">Hello {{myUsername}}</div>'
    + '<div ng-hide="myUsername">Sorry, No user to greet!</div></span>',
  };
});
```

Note that the template is wrapped in a <span> because a template needs to have one root element.  (Without the <span>, it would have two <div> root elements.)

The HTML needs to be modified slightly, to interpolate:

```
<hello-world my-username="{{names[0]}}"></hello-world>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/979mN/).

Comment: @Liviu, since the directive doesn't change the myUsername value, one-way databinding ('@') seems more appropriate than two-way databinding ('=').  Although using '=' is easier (no need to use {{}} in the HTML), using '@' makes it clear that the directive does not need to modify the value.

Comment: @MarkRajcok, Excellent information in last comment, We would love to see some more like this be shared via blog or video tutorial. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Code: http://jsbin.com/obuqip/9/edit

```
components.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    var directiveObj =  {
        compile:function(element, attrs) {
            var strTemplate, strUserT = attrs.myUsername || "";
            console.log(strUserT);
            if(strUserT) {
                strTemplate = "<DIV> Hello " + "{{" + strUserT +"}} </DIV>" ;
            } else {
                strTemplate = "<DIV>Sorry, No user to greet!</DIV>" ;
            }
            element.replaceWith(strTemplate);
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
    return directiveObj;
});
```

Explanation: The same code should be used in compile function rather than linking function. AngularJS does compile the generated content of compile function.

Comment: Since `element` is not used in the link function version of this directive (Liviu's answser), I agree that a compile function seems better.

Comment: I just posted an answer that doesn't even need a compile function.

Answer (score 9):

You need to create an angular element from the template and use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) service

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/obuqip/5/edit)

```
components.directive('helloWorld', ['$compile', function(compile) {
    var directiveObj =  {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var strTemplate, strUserT = attrs.myUsername || "";
            console.log(strUserT);
            if (strUserT) {
                strTemplate = "<DIV> Hello" + "{{" + strUserT +"}} </DIV>" ;
            } else {
                strTemplate = "<DIV>Sorry, No user to greet!</DIV>" ;
            }

            var e = angular.element(strTemplate);
            compile(e.contents())(scope);
            element.replaceWith(e);
        },
        template: function() {
            console.log(args);
            return "Hello";
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
    return directiveObj;
}]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs. Normally it's not an issue with 1:1 directive:html. ng-repeat and similar directives use the compile function to optimize.

Comment: This answer includes explanation from Misko http://stackoverflow.com/a/14359666/148869

Comment: @Liviu, what is the purpose of `template:` in the directive?  Were you trying to see if you could generate the two versions of the output there (and found it didn't work and forgot to remove the code, maybe)?  I'm curious to know if `template:` can take a function.

Comment: @MarkRajcok actually I just modified the OP's solution to include the compile service, frankly I didn't see the other parameters :)