# AngularJS nested-loop ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a table directive that can accept a wide variety of data sources, normalizing the markup. I ran into an issue where my data object for `rows` can have children of it's own.  Using [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357945/how-to-make-angularjs-compile-the-code-generated-by-directive), I constructed a new directive containing a recursive function to generate the HTML I desired, using this:

```
<nested-rows rows="rows" columns="columns"></nested-rows>
```

However, because of the dynamic nature of the row data, I'm not statically defining my td's.

Historically, I did this:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns">
  <cell-content renderer-id="column.rendererId" content="row[column.id]">
  </cell-content>
</td>
```

Where we're simply iterating the columns array, passing in the value of row.someColumn into a separate directive to generate different cell content (list, button, icon, etc..), where `row.someColumn` contains the necessary data for that particular column/column type.

The problem I'm having lies in this new directive. I don't have a variable `row` anymore, so calling `row[column.id]` is returning undefined. Here is my directive:

```
.directive('nestedRows', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = "";
            var recursive = function(rows) {
                angular.forEach(rows, function(row, index) {
                    html +=
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td ng-repeat="column in columns">' +
                            '<cell-content renderer-id="column.rendererId"' +
                                  'content="row[column.id]"></cell-content>' +
                            '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    if(row.children) {
                        recursive(row.children);
                    }
                })
            }
            if(attrs && attrs.rows) {
                recursive(attrs.rows);
            }
            element.html(html);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
})
```

What I need to do is pass the proper data to my cellContent directive. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to create a controller in your row directive and then 'require' it in your column directive.

In this context the controller is just a function which will be called when your parent directive is instantiated. Whatever is returned by the function will be passed to the  directive requesting the controller in the 4th parameter of its 'compile' method.

See my ng-scroller directive for an [example](https://github.com/Hill30/NGScroller)

Also see detailed description [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: You're going to make me read coffee script? :) Thanks for the response, it _sounds_ right, I'll take a look.

Comment: @ScottSilvi My sincere apologies :). Do not look at the code, look at the directive definitions

Comment: Ultimately this gave me what I wanted. Thanks!