# Initialising and re-initialising a component in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I encounter the problem of how to initialise and later re-initialise a directive/component in AngularJS ALL the time, and I'm not satisfied with any of my current approaches below.

Eg I have a `<clock>` directive/component, and it needs to be given the time from externally when I initialise the clock, so that the clock shows the correct time.

If the user updates the time from WITHIN clock, we can just set up an `onChangeTime` function as Tero does [here](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/10/18/refactoring-angular-apps-to-components.html#replace-external-effect-with-bound-output) with `onDelete` to update the parent.

But what if the time is changed by `clock`'s parent and the `clock` needs to be re-initialised with the new time?

It needs to be re-initialised, because perhaps, the time passed in needs to be parsed into hours, mins, seconds, etc for the purposes of `<clock>`.

I have used three ways:

### 1. Pass update function

`mainCtrl` makes a variable, eg `updateTime`, available (eg using '=' binding), and clock will upon initialising, set that variable to the internal function that will update the clock with the new time. `mainCtrl` can call `updateTime` whenever it needs to update the clock's time.

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.changeTime = function(time) {
    // do controller stuff
    vm.updateTime(time);  // this is clock's function
  }
})

.component('clock', {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    "updateTime": '='
  },
  controller: 'ClockController as vm'
});

function ClockController() {
  var vm = this;
  // initialise clock by passing the parent its update function
  vm.updateTime = function(time) {
    // use time arg to update internal clock variables such as 
    // hours, mins, secs, so that the clock displays the correct time
  }
}

...

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <clock update-time="vm.updateTime"></clock>
</div>
```

I like this approach, but you get "`updateTime` is not a function" when you need `clock` to show the time AS SOON AS `mainCtrl` initialises. Can be fixed with `$timeout` hacks, but yuck.

### 2. Pass update function and variable

Pass the `updateTime` function AND `time` (eg datetime object) as '=' parameters. Upon first initialisation, `clock` uses the `time` variable to set its internal time. And after that the `mainCtrl` can use `updateTime` to tell `clock` that the time has changed.

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.time = Date.now();

  vm.changeTime = function(time) {
    vm.time = time;
    vm.updateTime();  //notifies clock that time changed
  }
})

.component('clock', {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    "updateTime": '=',
    "time": '='
  },
  controller: 'ClockController as vm'
});

function ClockController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.updateTime = _initTime // for parent to re-initialise later

  function _initTime() {
    // use local vm.time to update internal clock variables such as 
    // hours, mins, secs, so that the clock displays the correct time
  }

  _initTime();  // first initialisation
}

...

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <clock update-time="vm.updateTime" time="vm.time"></clock>
</div>
```

This assumes that by the time `mainCtrl` needs to re-initialise the `clock`, `clock` has initialised, and therefore made the `updateClock` function available to `mainCtrl`, getting around the problem in 1.  This works, but it seems weird and redundant having a `updateTime` just to say "oh, by the way, I updated `time`".

### 3. Use a $watch

Just pass `time` and have `clock` put a `$watch` on it.

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.time = Date.now();

  vm.changeTime = function(time) {
    vm.time = time;
  }
})

.component('clock', {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    "time": '='
  },
  controller: 'ClockController as vm'
});

function ClockController($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  $scope.$watch('vm.time', function(newVal) {
    // use newVal to update internal clock variables such as 
    // hours, mins, secs, so that the clock displays the correct time
  }
}

...

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <clock time="vm.time"></clock>
</div>
```

I don't like $watches in general because of the performance issues.

What is the best (most Angular) way? Is there a better approach people can think of or recommend?