# Appending templates when ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation

I have a situation where a button is provided for the user to click. After clicking the button, a new `<div>` (which is actually a template with isolated scope) is created, and this `<div>` is appended to the existing element, like so:

```
<button ng-click="openNewDiv()"></button>
<div>Div content for DIV 1</div>
<div>Div content for DIV 2</div>
<div>Div content for DIV 3</div>
<div>Div content for DIV 4</div>
```

Each `<div>` shares the same template and logic, with isolated scope, when user clicks the button, a fifth `<div>` is appended next to `DIV4`, which also shares the same logic as the above 4 `<div>`'s, how can I achieve this in AngularJS? I am reading this article to find the solution, am I on the right direction?

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can achieved using directives, [see here for the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). You can make a directive which contains the template and logic for the `<div>` elements.  As for adding this directive multiple times when a button is clicked you can use an ngRepeat to iterate over an array containing the directive data.

In your controller:

```
$scope.myData = [dataDiv1, dataDiv2, ..., dataDivx];
$scope.openNewDiv = function() {
    $scope.myData.push(anotherDataDiv);
};
```

In your view:

```
<button ng-click="openNewDiv()"></button>
<my-directive myData="data" ng-repeat="data in myData"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification, I am wondering if $compile service is suitable in my case, so in this case $compile is not necessary?

Comment: I would use the `link` function instead of the `compile` function for your directive. [See this post for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/directive-link-vs-compile-vs-controller)

Comment: I am curious when should I use $compile, as from my search, $compile is to compile the newly made DOM to the existing one, which is somehow match my case

Comment: The biggest difference between `link` and `compile` is that `compile` only gets called once, irregardless if multiple copies are made of the directive (in our case by ng-repeat).