# In a custom directive, what functionality does `controller` have over `link`?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In trying to get a grasp on creating my own AngularJS directives, I have an example that does everything I need, but realize that in borrowing from various examples, I now can create functionality for the directive's view in both the **controller** as well as the **link**.

It seems that I could get rid of the **controller** all together and just put everything into **link**, or is there something that I can do with the controller that I can't do with link?

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/gxr49h96/6

```
.directive('itemMenu', function () {

    var controller = function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.addItem = function () {
            $scope.add();
            vm.items.push({
                'kind': 'undefined',
                    'firstName': 'Joe',
                    'lastName': 'Newton',
                    'age': Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20
            });
        };

        // DOES THE SAME AS THE FUNCTION DEFINED BELOW IN LINK        
        //        $scope.convertToInternal = function(item) {
        //            item.internalcode = 'X0000';
        //            item.kind = 'internal';
        //        };        
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            add: '&'
        },
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                switch (scope.item.kind) {
                    case 'external':
                        return 'itemMenuTemplateExternal';
                    case 'internal':
                        return 'itemMenuTemplateInternal';
                    default:
                        return 'itemMenuTemplateUndefined';
                }
            };

            scope.convertToInternal = function(item) {
                item.internalcode = 'X0000';
                item.kind = 'internal';
            };
        },
    };

})
```

Comment: I found a very good explanation for this here --
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/directive-link-vs-compile-vs-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find a lot of watery rants about controller vs link, most of them contain the information from [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service documentation.

Answering the question directly,

- controllers from other modules/files can be plugged into the directive via Angular DI with `controller: 'Controller'`
- `controller` can be injected with dependencies while `link` has fixed arguments list of and gets by with directive's dependencies
- `controller` kicks in before `link`, so it can prepare the scope for linking or recompile the element on some condition ASAP
- controller function has `this`, its code appearance complies to other OOP-like ES5 code, and the methods can be easily transferred between other code parts, e.g. `service` service or third-party code
- as the result, controllers are suited to be defined as [ES2015](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/es6/2015/01/23/exploring-angular-1.3-using-es6.html#angular-and-es-modules) or [TS](https://gist.github.com/esfand/9569523#controller-classes) classes.
- directive's controller can be `require`d by child directive and provides convenient one-way interaction between those two
- `controller` makes use of `bindToController: true` + `controllerAs: 'vm'` and implements `$scope.vm` recipe (particularly useful to fight JS prototypal inheritance) while keeping `this` syntax
- `bindToController` [object value](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10467) provides attribute bindings for inherited `scope: true` scope, no more `$attr.$observe`
- `bindToController` object value provides further granularity for isolated scope. If there are certain attributes that should be bound to the controller and accessed with `require`, it can be done now

Which code goes to `controller` and which to `link` is more delicate question.

It is conventional to use Angular controllers as view models, as in [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) (hence the `controllerAs: 'vm'` convention), so if there is a job for controllers (i.e. binding the services to scope values or setting up scope watchers) give it to them, leave the rest to `link`.

Since `$attrs`, `$element` and `$transclude` local dependencies should be injected into controller explicitly, the one may consider it a sign to skip them (`$scope` should be injected too for `$scope.$` methods, but we will just ignore this fact).

There are some non-religious concerns about the job that should be done by `link` and not by `controller`. `require`d controllers aren't available in controller itself, so this kind of directive interaction takes place in `link`. Since `controller` launches at earlier compilation phase than `link`, bound attribute values won't be interpolated yet, so the code that depends on these scope values goes to `link`. The same applies to other DOM-related code, it goes to `link` [for a reason](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#pre-linking-function).

It is mostly the matter of proper code style and not real necessity. As of the code in the example, all `scope` stuff is controller-friendly, I don't think that `link` should be there at all.

Comment: Thanks for this response. My main pragmatic take away from it is "use controller instead of link", which, as you suggested is possible in the above example, here I moved everything from link to controller and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/t7oxh9e0/1