# angularjs : how to get width from a $element in directive without using jquery

Tags: angularjs

I try to get a width from a $element in directive. but, it continues to return 0.

Can you tell me what is the problem? and, can you tell me the solution?

To see problem, i've created a demo :

- directive

  ```
  angular.module('testApp').directive('testDirective', testDirective)
  function testDirective() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          controller: 'TestController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          bindToController: true,
          scope: {}
      }
  }
  ```
- controller

  ```
  angular.module('testApp').controller('TestController', TestController);

  TestController.$inject = ['$element'];

  function TestController($element) {
      var vm = this;

      init()

      function init(){
      vm.elWidth0 = $element.find("div")[0].clientWidth; 
      vm.elWidth1 = $element.find("div")[0].offsetWidth; 
      vm.elWidth2 = $element.prop('clientWidth'); 
      console.log(vm.elWidth0); //return 0
      console.log(vm.elWidth1); //return 0
      console.log(vm.elWidth2); //return 0
      }
  }
  ```
- html

  ```
  <test-directive>
      <div>
          <button>a</button>
          <button>c</button>
          <button>d</button>
          <button>e</button>
          <button>f</button>
      </div>
  </test-directive>
  ```

Thank you for your advice

Comment: The most probable explanation is that the element has not actually rendered yet. You should probably use the `link` / `link.post` function to run your height detection code and even then, you may need to run it in a `$timeout`

Comment: hi @Phil. What should i do if necessary in a controller. and, Is the '$timeout' way a best practice?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3D8kQUukMkXRld9kNYJ1?p=preview

It would appear that you're not getting a proper reference to the elements. Try using `querySelector` instead:

```
$element[0].querySelector('button').clientWidth;
```

**UPDATE**

The best place to put DOM manipulation in a directive is in the `link` function(which is actually `post-link`) because link happens after the directive html has been compiled.

The controller also is created after the directive html has been compiled but it's good to use the controller to separate logic that requires communication with an angular service.  There's some really good information on directive link vs. controller [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller).

Your directive could then look something like this:

```
function testDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'TestController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {}, 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.elWidth0 = element.find("div")[0].clientWidth; 
      scope.elWidth1 = element.find("div")[0].offsetWidth; 

      console.log(scope.elWidth0);
      console.log(scope.elWidth1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @paultrone. I'm so so sorry. I had created a wrong demo. So, i corrected a demo