# AngularJS passing a scope variable within a string to a directive

Tags: angularjs, string, directive

I'm fairly new to AngularJS Directives and was wondering how I could implement passing a custom string, which is a url that contains a controller variable, to be used later on by that controller?

Calling Directive

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-custom-form after-submit="group/{{insertedId}}" />
</div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('myCustomForm', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'myCustomForm.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.loadUrl = attr.afterSubmit;
        }
    }
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.loadUrl = '';
    $scope.insertedId = NULL;
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'edit.php',   
        data:formData
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.insertedId = response.dbInsertedPrimaryId; // used in "after-submit"
        $location.path($scope.loadUrl); 
    });
});
```

So when $location.path() called it sends me to a url for example:

```
http://example.com/group/22
```

The reason for this is so that I can pass a specific/different url each time the directive is used, like so

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-custom-form after-submit="user/{{insertedId}}" />
    <my-custom-form after-submit="home/{{insertedId}}/something" />
    <my-custom-form after-submit="{{insertedId}}/anything" />
</div>
```

Or maybe there is a better way to do this? I don't know that's why I'm asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
app.directive('myCustomForm', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
          afterSubmit = '@',
        },
        templateUrl: 'myCustomForm.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.afterSubmit);
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that the scope variable name is camelCase (stackOverflow), instead the attribute is dash-case (stack-overflow)
This because HTML cannot understand camelCase and javascript cannot understand dash-case

The @ for the variable stand for string. You can use:

- @ for strings
- = for variables coming from the controller (ex: after-submit="ctrl.submitUrl")
- & for callbacks (ex: on-submit="ctrl.submit()")

You should use controller: instead of link: ... Here the reason: [AngularJS : link vs compile vs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller)

Comment: This: `controller: function(scope, element, attr) {}` doesn't appear to be the syntax for the directive's controller!

Comment: What about dynamic injection?, I mean something like: `controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {}]`

Comment: It's not mandatory.. I have a grunt plugin that changes it everytime I build so i don't have to add two things everytime i declare something new.