# Cannot acces form state on a directive Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angularjs v1.2.21 and I cannot access form state inside a directive, with another versions this works( I cannot change project Angularjs version)... I created a plunkr below:

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmnqKfMtoF95tNAUAFJQ?p=preview)

```
.directive('testReplace', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  replace: true,
  scope:{ 
     transaction: '=',
     isvalid: '='
  },
  templateUrl: 'modal-back.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log($scope.myForm)
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.myForm is there, i believe it is because you need to use link instead of controller, unless you are waiting for something to happen (like a click event or something) in the form. So try changing it to this

from :

```
controller: function($scope){
```

to:

```
link: function($scope){
```

You use link because the link phase is when you are actually attaching the data, so when you log you will see the correct information

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eCW1lrsS5GTbmoA9JAcL?p=preview

Also, if you would like to ready more and controller vs link vs compile, there is a great thread on it here : [AngularJS : link vs compile vs controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller)

Comment: thank you for your help. that works for me! It's weird, because with another versions I can access that form state using controller.

Comment: I have another question, if I need to use Controller and Link I get an compilation error. This is normal

Comment: @John what is the error saying? Also why both? Everything you can do in controller, you can do in link.

Comment: I can also private scope if I use Link?

Answer (score 3):

Use link function instead of controller : http://plnkr.co/edit/EI8qVhh9pOBiEtD4koGB?p=preview

---

```
link: function(scope){
       console.log(scope.myForm)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. that works for me! It's weird, because with another versions I can access that form state using controller.

Comment: I have another question, if I need to use Controller and Link I get an compilation error. This is normal

Comment: @John : Why do you want both ? What error are you getting ?