# Angular Directive - Correct order of execution of functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

Being bit confused as per the following 2 blogs:

> **I.** Eric W Green - Toptal 
>   https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-js-demystifying-directives

Order of execution

```
Compile -> Controller -> PreLink -> PostLink
```

> **II.** JsonMore
>   http://jasonmore.net/angular-js-directives-difference-controller-link/

Order of execution

```
Controller -> Compile -> PreLink -> PostLink
```

The answer to complex problem difference between *controller* & *link* is given here -- use code in controller if required before compile ***OR*** write in link if code to be run after compile.

But, blog 1 says both run after compilation. Please, suggest which one is correct?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller See comments of most up-voted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is as a matter of fact baffling , but ones you understand the actual flow, it would remain clear throughout.

The actual order of execution is ..**Compile -> Controller -> Pre-Link -> Post-Link**

For further understanding, just go through this [article](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/), it surely helped me.

Hope this helps.

Cheers