# Angular link and controller options in the directive declaration

Tags: angularjs

While reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) I can see usage of both: link method and directive options.
Can both of these options be present in directive declaration at the same time?

Comment: link is one of the options you can use. I don't really understand your question

Comment: and controller is one of the options I can use, so question is: can I use both options in the directive declaration at the same time?

Comment: If you mean `link` vs `controller` in a directive, you'd use the second when you want to expose functionality with other directives. Otherwise use `link`.

Comment: so what if I want 'to expose functionality' and 'manipulate the DOM'?

Comment: there is more than 2 options (you have compile, pre-link, post-link, controller). You can use alll of them together. You can google "directive lifecycle" for more explanation

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller?rq=1

Comment: You can't use 'compile' and 'link' together. You must choose what 'phase' fits better to you. Is it the same with 'link' and 'controller' for a directive declaration, or they can be used side by side?

Comment: You can use link,  compile and controller together - no problem.

Answer (score 0):

So all can be used together, thanks Deblaton.

```
.directive("directiveName",function () {

  return {
    controller: function() {
      // controller code here...
    },
    compile: {

      // compile code here...

      return {

        pre: function() {
          // pre-link code here...
        },

        post: function() {
          // post-link code here...
        }
      };
    }
  }
})
```