# Can't access any route inside my template directive

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive, where I'm trying to get some news via HTTP GET method, based on some options

```
import publicListTpl from './public-list.html';

(() => {
    angular
        .module('news.crud.directives', [])
        .directive('newsPortalPublishedList', () => ({
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: publicListTpl,
            scope: {
                type: '@'
            },
            controller: ($scope, $http, FlashMessages) => {
                $http.get('/api/portal/'+$scope.type)
                    .then(response => $scope.news = response.data)
                    .catch(() => FlashMessages.add(FlashMessages.ERROR, 'La récupération des '+$scope.type+' a échoué.'));
            }
        })); })();
```

The problem that when I add the `scope` option `scope: {type: '@'}`, I cant access to any defined route into my `publicListTpl` template, for example `url('news_edit', {id: news.id})` will return `null`.

This is my html template:

```
<div class="portlet" ng-repeat="news in newsList">
    <div class="portlet light bordered">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                {{ news.title }}
                <small>{{ news.subtitle }}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ url('news_edit', {id: news.id}) }}">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editer
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <img ng-if="news.image" src="{{ news.image }}" class="pull-left" height="100"/>
            <div ng-bind-html="news.shortContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ps: I don't even know the source problem, so you can edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: post your HTML code that uses this directive

Comment: @PeterWilson done (y)

Comment: as I understand you want to create directive to do http calls depending on options you want to to set in the HTML, am I right?

Comment: that doesn't look right: `ng-repeat="news in news._embedded.items"`, you are overriding the array with an inner element (array?)

Comment: Yes, that's it, could you propose me some solution to test them

Comment: That's good the API returning data like that, and I'm getting my data right, everything works good, just   `{{url('news_edit')}}` not working ...it return blank

Comment: `{{ }}` takes angularjs expressions, it thinks `url` is `$scope.url = function(...){...}` in your controller. Additionally you might need `ng-href` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes to your directive, I used link function instead of controller and I replaced `news` in `ng-repeat` with `item` because it's not a good choice to name the single items with name of the array your are looping through.

```js
import publicListTpl from './public-list.html';
    
    (() => {
        angular
            .module('news.crud.directives', [])
            .directive('newsPortalPublishedList', ($http, FlashMessages) => ({
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: publicListTpl,
                scope: {
                    type: '@'
                },
                link: (scope) => {
                    $http.get('/api/portal/'+scope.type)
                        .then(response => scope.news = response.data)
                        .catch(() => FlashMessages.add(FlashMessages.ERROR, 'La récupération des '+scope.type+' a échoué.'));
                }
            })); })();
```

```html
<div class="portlet" ng-repeat="item in news._embedded.items">
        <div class="portlet light bordered">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    {{ item.title }}
                    <small>{{ item.subtitle }}</small>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ url('news_edit', {id: item.id}) }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editer
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">
                <img ng-if="news.image" src="{{ item.image }}" class="pull-left" height="100"/>
                <div ng-bind-html="news.shortContent"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the using of the directive should be :

```
<news-portal-published-list type="url_goes_here"></news-portal-published-list>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for you answer with some few modify, it works great, just can explain to me the difference between `controller:` and `link:`

Comment: you can read about  the differences between them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/link-vs-compile-vs-controller
but simply `link` used to bind data between directive scope and the controller of the view that called the directive, `controller` used on directive-to-directive communication