# Are the link functions differernt in directive compile returning and link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

**[UPDATE]**: Got answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs)(which takes time to read, so I just quote a simple answer of **my understanding to that post here**):

> "Note that if you need a compile function and a link function (or pre
>   and post link functions), the compile function must return the link
>   function(s) because the 'link' attribute is ignored if the 'compile'
>   attribute is defined."

I am pretty new to AngularJS directive, when I learn how to use $compile, I got one question, for example:

I can define a directive like:

```
app.directive("customdir", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        compile: function(tmplEL, attrs){
            return function(scope, EL, attrs){/*this is the link function*/};
        },
        link: function(scope, EL, attrs){/*this is also the link function*/}
    }
})
```

My confusion here is: the compile function return a link function while we can define another link function in directive as well, **are they same function** or they are different function that the `link: function(scope, EL, attrs)` can override the `link function returned from compile`?

And what is the result **if I defined both**?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs

Comment: @K.Toress Thanks, that clear my confuse, I will update my post and add the straight answer to it.

Comment: @K.Toress Could you help me with another question, I post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215947/what-happended-to-the-dom-node-when-angularjs-compile-a-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an "either/or".

You can define a `compile` property on the directive declaration object, which is a function that returns a `link` function/object - then the `link` property is ignored.

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude){
  return {
    pre: function prelink(){...},
    post: function postlink(){...}
  };
}
```

Or, since `compile` function is less commonly used, you could just specify the `link` property - which could be the post-link function (if it's a function value) or both pre-link and post-link, if it's an object value with these fields:

```
link: {
  pre: function prelink(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
  },
  post: function postlink(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
  }
}
```

Or simply:

```
link: function postlink(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
}
```

More info in Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

Comment: Thanks for help. After reading the post, I finally figure out the relation between the link func returned from compile and the definition in directive attr.