# Angular directives settings pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a good design pattern to provide angular directives render acording to some global specified parametrs.
For example, I have some factory called "Settings", that holds the value "directiveColor: red".
When i do the link in my directive, I ask the Settings about my directiveColor value. Everything is working fine - I got red and put element on the page. But I have hundreds of this elements on the page, and every directive before render ask for settings... I think it's not very good way. 
What will you recomend?

UPD

factory

```
app.factory('Settings', function() {
    var data = {
        //...
        directiveColor: red //set by user
    }
    //...
    GetSettings : function () {return data}
}
```

directve

```
app.directive('wdMyDirective', ['Settings', function(Settings) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.data = {
                //...
                color:  Settings.GetSettings().directiveColor
            };
    };
}]);
//later "color" used in template through the scope
```

That's how it works for now (works fine). But every time, when I render directive (many many times on the page, ngRepeat for table data), my directive ask for Settings to choose its color. I think, it is not good. Or maybe not?

Comment: Whare is the code to improve? Do you have any performance problem? If not, why do you care?

Comment: I'm new to angular, but it sounds like defining a service which you can get injected into your directives or on demand would be a good clean soloution.  something like $settings

Comment: @eranotzap the $ prefix is a namespace used by angular to avoid clashes betwee angular-provided services and application services. Application servises should NOT be prefixed by a $.

Comment: @JBNizet good to know. thanks i wasn't aware of that. Any thoughts on providing a settings service..? is there a built in service which can be used for this purpose ?

Comment: No, no such service exists. But it seems the user just wants a constant or value.

Comment: "I think it's not very good way" is merely your assertion, but you have to, at least, specify what problems (performance, code cleanness / maintenability / flexibility) you foresee and would like to avoid

Comment: I've updated the post, please look

Comment: @eranotzap he already have settings service. Factory and Service are the same thing in angular with exception that Service is called with `new`.

Comment: @vittore when i wrote that comment 4 hours ago he didn't have any code written down :)

Comment: @JBNizet a constant would pollute the global namespace. That potentially might later cause unexpected errors.

Comment: @eranotzap he is talking about angular thing `angular.module('a').constant(...)` and `angular.module('a').value(...)`

Answer (score 2):

There are two considerations here. First, you are right that it is not optimal, and directive actually provides a way to do that call once, read about [Compile-PreLink-PostLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs) in angular directives. Basically you want this call in Compile step if it is the same for all directives in your app.

Second consideration is that `Settings.GetSettings().directiveColor` will give really really small overhead if `GetSettings()` returns just an object that you only create once ( and that is what happened as angular factories are singletons )

In your case you can do

```
app.factory('Settings', function() {
  var data = {
      directiveColor: 'red' //set by user
  }

  return {
      GetSettings : function () {return data}
  }
})

app.directive('wdMyDirective', ['Settings', function(Settings) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',       
    compile: function(elem, attrs) {             
        var color = Settings.GetSettings().directiveColor 
        return function postLink(scope, elem, attr) {
           scope.data = {
              color:  color
           };
        }
    }
  }
}])
```

instead of declaring link property on directive.

Comment: is settings a service he created ?