# Why angular {{}} syntax prevent the change from attrs.$set in directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

When apply angular syntax `{{}}` on element, directive `attrs.$set` will not work.

**Edit:**
My question is could anyone explain **why**?

If `{{}}` parsed and then `link`, why wouldn't the element been modified by `link`?

If `link` first, `{{}}` should be removed, both condition will not result like this.

Here is the [code pen](http://codepen.io/Asing1001/pen/grreKK?editors=1111)

```
<div ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="global">
  <a aaa href="http://{{::lan}}/4567">has syntax</a>
  <a aaa href="http://nosyntax/4567">no syntax</a>
</div>

angular.module('ngApp',[])
  .directive('aaa',function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope, ele, attr){
      attr.$set('href','http://fromdirective');
    }
  }
}).controller('global',function($scope){
  $scope.lan = 'en-gb';
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are leveraging `link`, the framework has already attached data to the element in question, parsing the `{{}}`syntax (digest cycle). If you want to set this value *before* the element is compiled, you can leverage [`compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) in place of `link` as such...

```
.directive('aaa',function(){
  return {
    compile: function(tElement, tAttributes, transcludeFn) {

      // -- just a jqLite object at this point
      tAttributes.$set('href','http://fromdirective');
    }
  }
```

[updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXXLqJ?editors=1011)

Unsure if this is your intention, but this is why it is happening. As others have suggested, `$timeout` will avoid the digest issue as well, but *after* `link` has initially digested - you'll need to determine which is more appropriate per your use case.

See SO question [What is the difference between compile and link function in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs) for some more discussion on this topic. Also check out the [ngHref directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) - perhaps this could be useful.

Comment: Thanks your answer, the compile function did the work to override the `{{}} ` syntax, however why the link function can not modify after {{}} has been parsed?

Comment: @AndyChen my best guess is because there is a lock of sort which forces you to wait in the midst of this digest cycle, or do it before. I'm guessing you'll need to dig through the framework to find your exact answer, since it's very specific and not commonly looked further into more than "`$timeout` works - good enough" (guilty myself)

Comment: @AndyChen did you make any more progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
angular.module('ngApp',[])
  .directive('aaa',['$timeout',function($timeout){
  return {
    link:function(scope, ele, attr){
      $timeout(function() {
      attr.$set('href','http://fromdirective');
      },0);
    }
  }
}]).controller('global',function($scope){
  $scope.lan = 'en-gb';
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know why will behave like this ?

Comment: Interest... want to know too

Comment: because {{}} executing after directive.

Comment: but as you said, directive should already change the href, so {{}} will be removed, am I wrong?

Comment: as mentioned below, more than 1 digest occurred.
If you are setting timeout, first digest will execute, and then ,on timeout(0),next digest will occur. without timeout executing only last - {{}}

Answer (score 1):

Use `$timeout` to push the change to the end of the digest cycle

```
angular.module('ngApp',[])
  .directive('aaa',function($timeout){
  return {
    link:function(scope, ele, attr){
      $timeout(function(){
         attr.$set('href','http://fromdirective');
      });         
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know why will behave like this ?

Comment: because of digest cycles. More than one digest occurs in a cycle and you are changing it while angular is still aware of the original binding internally