# when to use link function and compile function in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

> I am still confuse where to use link and compile function.
>
> > Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link function is used in a directive.

The params of the link function reference the element the directive is attached to.

```
link: function(scope, element, attr)
```

Element here is the HTML element. and attr refers to the attributes of the HTML element

So you could do element.text('fred');

To set the text of the element to 'fred' and so on.

$compile I am not so familiar

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14300374/4281154)

> **compile function** - use for template DOM manipulation (i.e.,
>   manipulation of tElement = template element), hence manipulations that
>   apply to all DOM clones of the template associated with the directive.
>
> **link function** - use for registering DOM listeners (i.e., $watch
>   expressions on the instance scope) as well as instance DOM
>   manipulation (i.e., manipulation of iElement = individual instance
>   element).