# $document.ready() on directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a directive that returns a template that does not appear to be sizing itself as it should. Elements in the template have their height set to 100%, however, it seems the parent's height (outside the directive) is not being set quick enough (also from 0 to 100%).

I do not have an issue if I refresh the page, this only comes up when resizing the window.

**Example:** http://codepen.io/sweatherly/pen/rLYPvE  (decrease the window size, then refresh to see)

Please note the the example does not use a directive, just highlights the problem.

```
(function() {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("ngApp")
    .directive("currentCard", function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'components/orders/current/current-card.tpl.html',
            scope: {
                orders:     "=",
                cardTitle:  "@cardTitle"
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Is it possible to somehow use `$document.ready()` on/with the template?
**Edit:** It turned out to be a stupid CSS issue (targeting wrong element), but I know understand a bit about directive's link function.

Comment: You can use link function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `link` function which will be executed after the template is loaded.

Usually any DOM manipulation, adding/removing event handlers should be done in link function.

Please refer [difference between compile and link function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs) .

Comment: It turned out to be a different issue, but thanks for the compile/link explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the link function...

**Link** is a built in feature for directive, this function is executed when the directive is loaded or appears in the parent template.

Reference [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) ; example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate')

```
(function() {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("ngApp")
    .directive("currentCard", function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'components/orders/current/current-card.tpl.html',
            scope: {
                orders:     "=",
                cardTitle:  "@cardTitle"
            },
            link: function(){
               console.log("ready")
            }
        }
    });
 })();
```

Comment: Is the solution to modify the elements where `height: 0px`, changing them to `height: 100%` from inside the link function? Or is there a way to call or rerender the template from link?

Comment: The template will automatically render when the link is called. The link is called when the directive is exposed to the user @sweatherly

Comment: It turned out to be a different (CSS) issue, but thanks for the explanation.