# Angularjs : How can i know when to use "Compile" when to use "Link" in directives?

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, compilation

I am very new to angularjs. I have little bit confusion with link and compile usage in directives. Can anyone please tell me in which scenarios we have to use link and compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between compile and link function in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs)

Comment: Do some research please before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

> [What is the difference between compile and link function in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs)

Already answered on stack overflow and has an excellent explanation

Answer (score 0):

**The compile phase**

**When the DOM is loaded Angular starts the compile phase,** where it traverses the markup top-down, and calls compile on all directives. Graphically, we could express it like so:

An image illustrating the compilation loop for children

It is perhaps important to mention that at this stage, the templates the compile function gets are the source templates (not instance template).

**The link phase**

DOM instances are often simply the result of a source template being rendered to the DOM, but they may be created by ng-repeat, or introduced on the fly.

**Whenever a new instance of an element with a directive is rendered to the DOM, the link phase starts.**

In this phase, Angular calls controller, pre-link, iterates children, and call post-link on all directives, like so:

Below links will give you clear idea for compile vs link.

[Angular directives - when and how to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post)

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx